# Почему появляется ошибка POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/data.xml 405 (Method Not Allowed)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Л.р.7</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="buttonsBlock">
      <button id="button_1">Кнопка #1</button>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button_1').click(function() {
          console.log('Нажали');
          $.post("data.xml", function(data) {
            $(data).find("country").each(function() {
              var name = $(this).find("name").text();
              console.log(name) }); }); }); });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Я хочу что бы нажатию на кнопку из XML-файла подгружалась информация. Вылазит ошибка.

Comment: А зачем вы используете post?

Comment: Это лабораторная работа в универе. В задании сказано использовать метод jQuery.post

Comment: post для получения данных? Стукните того, кто составлял задание, потому что это звучит как бред. Ну или вы неправильно его поняли

Comment: Цитирую задание: " ... При нажатии на первую кнопку должны подгружаться данные из 3 XML файлов с использованием метода jQuery.post ... "

Comment: Ну да, всё ещё бред. Тогда вам придётся обучать свой веб-сервер обрабатывать POST-запросы